# How can get the text of <a> tag without id using only javascript

Tags: javascript

I am attaching a javascript to the following a tag section

```
<a class="btn-button button" onclick="myAlert()">
</a>
```

And this is my javascript function

```
<script>
    function myAlert() {
        alert('Test..');
    }
</script>
```

How can I get the current text been assigned when the javascript will fire?
As you can see there is not id been set in the `a` tag.

**EDIT**
I know that right now there is not value but I was just copy my actually code. At some point there will be a values since it is used from other components including Angular.

Comment: This is not very clear, which "assigned text" are you talking about? Note that in your code, the `a` opening tag misses the closing `>`. A little hint: you can use `onclick="myAlert(this)"` to pass the HTML element to the function..

Comment: Thank you for the missing closing tag. Currently there is no text or value that is displayed but this section is share among other components. So, when it runs there is a text and when the javascript fires I need to check the current text. I will try your suggestion. Also some Angular code uses it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell which proper Angular way to do this as you haven't shared Angular code, but this is how it can be done in vanilla HTML/JS:

In the `onclick`, set `this` as an argument to your function, so that you can receive the HTML element that called it.

Then you can use either `textContent` or `innerText` (see list of their differences in [this MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)) to get or change the text value.

```js
function myAlert(element) {
    alert('Test..' + element.textContent);
    //adding something so that we can see it's dynamic
    element.textContent += ' bla';
}
```

```html
<a class="btn-button button" onclick="myAlert(this)">
click me</a>
```

Comment: You're welcome, as a little advice, it's better to polish your question before posting it, as people that downvote or VTC rarely come back to see if the OP improved the question to adapt their vote

Comment: You are right, I will try even been at work and try to solve an issue is not that easy. Thanks